# How do you choose the timeframe for a prediction to be tested?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, correlation, predictive-models

To (hopefully) clarify the question a bit more if you have a broad working hypothesis that x influences y, on a causal/predictive basis (e.g. if x goes up in time t, then you would expect y to go up in time t+1, assuming the working hypothesis is true).

In traditional time-series analysis the length of time that the period t represents for t and t+1 tends to be equal. Can alterations in the periods that each represents, be easily altered for the purposes of analysis?

Also if we take the example of t to be a day, is it possible to distinguish differences in predictivity for various time frames, e.g. x goes up today, and over the course of the next 3 days y goes up, or over the course of the next 5 days y goes down (what happens if they are both significant?).

How does one go about detecting the time-frame of prediction appart from brute-forcing every possible combination of before and after timeframes (e.g. testing if x has gone up over the course of the last m days what happens to y over the next 1 to n days).

Answer (score 2):

The time frame of prediction i.e. the size of the "bucket" is set by you. You select whether tou wish to react/respond to hourly data or daily data or other frequencies.  Data arrives as transactions and is hen bucketed to time intervals. This time interval is your choice. We are developing forecats at 15 minute intervals for major food chains and others while incorporating daily trends/factors that are driven by promotions/events. THe quality of the predictivity can be measured for different size buckets for different lead times.

Comment: If I interpret the OP correctly he is asking about using unequally spaced time points.  Using the term causal takes the question into a different realm than prediction.  But I think he just means that he has a second time series that crosscorrelates at lag 1 with the original series. Of course how far he wants to project ahead in up to him.  But I think he wants to know how you would handle unequal spacing (not commonly assumed in time series analysis).  I would assume that the two series are synchronized with the same variable spacing.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the clarification. If he wishes to relate two time series , one at a different level of aggregation/bucket size then he has to convert one of the series. In the case of y being monthly and x being quarterly, I have delivered code that linearly interpolates the quarterly numbers to obtain "monthly estimates". One could use a quadratic in time to interpolate as an alternative.

Comment: @ IrishStat and @Michael you are both right in terms of the question I was originally asking. Thank you to the both of you for contributing. The main question was what IrishStat was addressing, and I understand that it is my "choice" as to the "size of the bucket" but are there any broad suggestions, as to HOW exactly its chosen, should it be optimised? The synchronization issue solutions suggested are what I suspected would be the answers, but was curious to ask it, incase anybody had heard of more inventive solutions that don't make so many strong assumptions about interpolation.